# Combinations in of nested lists in python based on a one key attribute

Tags: python, list, nested, combinations

I don't know how to describe this. I'll show an example:
Here's my input list

```
[[0,25], [1,54], [2,76], [3,13], [4,79]]
```

This is the output I want:

```
[[[0,25], [1,54]], [[0,25], [1,54]], [[0,25], [2,76]], ...]
```

i.e I want A list containing all the combinations of inner lists taken 2 at a time, based on the first field of the inner list.

I tried itertools like this:

```
perm_list = itertools.combinations(task_list, 10)
```

But all it does is show this:

```
itertools.combinations object at 0x0120B060
```

Comment: `itertools` calls return iterators; to get a list, call `list()` on them: `perm_list = list(perm_list)`.

Comment: I don't understand your output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> nums = [[0,25], [1,54], [2,76], [3,13], [4,79]]
>>> list(combinations(nums, r=2))
[([0, 25], [1, 54]), ([0, 25], [2, 76]), ([0, 25], [3, 13]), ([0, 25], [4, 79]), ([1, 54], [2, 76]), ([1, 54], [3, 13]), ([1, 54], [4, 79]), ([2, 76], [3, 13]), ([2, 76], [4, 79]), ([3, 13], [4, 79])]
```

As the name implies, `itertools.combinations` returns an iterator (yields combinations lazily), you must consume the iterator with the `list(...)` constructor to obtain your list. Usually the iterator is preferable though, since you probably only need to iterate over the combinations.

```
for a, b in combinations(nums, r=2):
    pass
```

Don't construct a list if you don't need to store the result.

Comment: Why did you use r=2? Can't i give just 2?

Comment: And can anyone point me to the algorithm for generating k sized subsets of a given array? I saw lots of codes on the internet but I don't understand it:(

Comment: @user2138665 of course you can do it without `r=`, try it for yourself! "point me to the algorithm for generating k sized subsets of a given array" is this (http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) what you mean

Comment: I did try it without r and it worked:) Just wanted to know what r was for

Comment: @Frkdiablo seems to be `k` in mathematical notation, not sure why it was called `r` instead